# Is there some way else than document.createElement("tag") to create an element and set the tag later?

Tags: javascript

I want to create an Element object without a `tagName` property defined in it and later setting it? Is there some way I could do it, I know that the `tagName` is the read only property but I want to create an Element without actually specifying the `tagName`. Any workaround?

Comment: No, there's no such thing as an element without a name. There's a `documentFragment`, which can be used as a generic container though. Perhaps you could describe what you're ultimately after.

Comment: Don't think it's possible, only through the (questionably right) usage of `innerHTML`.

Comment: @squint that should be an answer :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Yeah, I was hoping OP would explain what he's ultimately after. Given that he had just asked about the relationship between `.prototype` and `__proto__`, it seemed as though he may have been trying to create custom DOM elements. And now that he's asked a couple more inheritance-based questions, my suspicions are stronger. I guess he'll learn eventually that it just won't work... at least not with a DOM element as the prototype object.